# eclipse set javascript source type to module

Tags: javascript, eclipse, webpack

I have a javascript project in eclipse neon.  I have installed the Enide 2015 plugin.  Our project is an html and javascript only.

I have some js files that are webpack modules.  So they have and "import" statement at the top.  Eclipse is telling me that is an error. (Unexpected token)  I did a quick search and I found that Eclipse needs to think of that file as a module and not a script file.

How is this achieved? I can't find anything like that in the project properties.

Comment: Is this the latest version of Eclipse IDE you're using?

Comment: Yes, Neon,  and I seem to be getting "SP"  spelling errors to.  I think I am just going to use Atom for my front end stuff.  Eclipse just does not seem to handle it well,  or not easily anyway.  Maybe it's just me.  We do have a weird structure.

Answer (score 0):

There's a relevant setting at: Preferences > Javascript > Validation > Source type: module.